# python; counting elements of vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, count

I would like to count and save in a vector `a` the number of elements of an array that are greater than a certain value `t`. I want to do this for different `t`s.

eg

My vector:`c=[0.3 0.2 0.3 0.6 0.9 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.1]`

I would like to count the number of elements of `c` that are greater than `t=0.9`, than `t=0.8` than `t=0.7` etc... I then want to save the counts for each different value of t in a vector

my code is (not working):

```
for t in range(0,10,1):
    for j in range(0, len(c)):    
        if c[j]>t/10:
            a.append(sum(c[j]>t))
```

my vector a should be of dimension 10, but it isn't!

Anybody can help me out?

Comment: do you want to count from .9 to 0?

Comment: yes! but I guess it shouldn't change if I count from 0 to 0.9, this way should be easier and I can use the range() command

Comment: And all your `c` values lie in `[0,1]` interval?

Comment: yes, no element of `c` is outside the `[0,1]` range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a function that loops over the array and just counts whenever the value is greater than the supplied threshold

```
c=[0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1]

def num_bigger(threshold):
    count = 0
    for num in c:
        if num > threshold:
            count +=1

    return count

thresholds = [x/10.0 for x in range(10)]

for thresh in thresholds:
    print thresh, num_bigger(thresh)
```

Note that the function checks for strictly greater, which is why, for example, the result is 0 when the threshold is .9.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things wrong with your code.

> my vector a should be of dimension 10, but it isn't!

That's because you don't append only 10 elements in your list. Look at your logic.

```
for t in range(0,10,1):
    for j in range(0, len(c)):    
        if c[j]>t/10:
            a.append(sum(c[j]>t))
```

For each threshold, `t`, you iterate over all 12 items in `c` one at a time and you append something to the list. Overall, you get 120 items. What you should have been doing instead is (in pseudocode):

```
for each threshold:
    count = how many elements in c are greater than threshold
    a.append(count)
```

`numpy.where()` gives you the indices in an array where a condition is satisfied, so you just have to count how many indices you get each time. We'll get to the full solution is a moment.

Another potential error is `t/10`, which in Python 2 is integer division and will return 0 for all thresholds. The correct way would be to force float division with `t/10.`. If you're on Python 3 though, you get float division by default so this might not be a problem. Notice though that you do `c[j] > t`, where `t` is between 0 and 10. Overall, your `c[j] > t` logic is wrong. You want to use a counter for all elements, like other answers have shown you, or collapse it all down to a one-liner list comprehension.

Finally, here's a solution fully utilising numpy.

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1])

thresh = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
counts = np.empty(thresh.shape, dtype=int)

for i, t in enumerate(thresh):
    counts[i] = len(np.where(c > t)[0])

print counts
```

Output:

```
[12 10  8  5  5  3  2  1  1  0]
```

Letting numpy take care of the loops under the hood is faster than Python-level loops. For demonstration:

```
import timeit

head = """
import numpy as np

c = np.array([0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1])

thresh = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
"""

numpy_where = """
for t in thresh:
    len(np.where(c > t)[0])
"""

python_loop = """
for t in thresh:
    len([element for element in c if element > t])
"""

n = 10000

for test in [numpy_where, python_loop]:
    print timeit.timeit(test, setup=head, number=n)
```

Which on my computer results in the following timings.

```
0.231292377372
0.321743753994
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

`if c[j]>t/10:`

Notice that both t and 10 are integers and so you perform integer division.
The easiest solution with the least changes is to change it to:

`if c[j]>float(t)/10:`

to force float division

So the whole code would look something like this:

```
a = []
c = [0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1]
for i in range(10): #10 is our 1.0 change it to 9 if you want to iterate to 0.9
    sum = 0
    cutoff = float(i)/10
    for ele in c:
        if ele <= cutoff:
            sum += ele
    a.append(sum)
print(len(a)) # prints 10, the numbers from 0.0 - 0.9
print(a) # prints the sums going from 0.0 cutoff to 1.0 cutoff
```

Comment: It is still doing the wrong thing. the first thing I checked is the dimension of `a`, which should be 10; for each `t` I want to know how many elements of `c` are greater than  `t`.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking now, that was just a change in the outer most loop to iterate over the numbers 0.0 - 0.9 (or 1.0) I wasn't sure which.

Answer (score 1):

You have to divide t / 10.0 so the result is a decimal, the result of t / 10 is an integer

```
a = []
c=[0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1]
for t in range(0,10,1):
    count = 0
    for j in range(0, len(c)):
        if c[j]>t/10.0:
            count = count+1
    a.append(count)
for t in range(0,10,1):
    print(str(a[t]) + ' elements in c are bigger than ' + str(t/10.0))
```

Output:

```
12 elements in c are bigger than 0.0
10 elements in c are bigger than 0.1
8 elements in c are bigger than 0.2
5 elements in c are bigger than 0.3
5 elements in c are bigger than 0.4
3 elements in c are bigger than 0.5
2 elements in c are bigger than 0.6
1 elements in c are bigger than 0.7
1 elements in c are bigger than 0.8
0 elements in c are bigger than 0.9
```

You can check the test [here](http://codepad.org/QZo01R8Q)

Comment: all elements of `a` have the same value, which is wrong. For each value of `t` the count of elements of `c` that is bigger than a certain `t` varies

Comment: No, the elements in a are different, please check the edited answer and the link where the code is tested.

Answer (score 1):

If you simplify your code bugs won't have places to hide!

```
c=[0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1]    
a=[]    
for t in [x/10 for x in range(10)]:
    a.append((t,len([x for x in c if x>t])))

a
[(0.0, 12),
 (0.1, 10),
 (0.2, 8),
 (0.3, 5),
 (0.4, 5),
 (0.5, 3),
 (0.6, 2),
 (0.7, 1),
 (0.8, 1),
 (0.9, 0)]
```

or even this one-liner

```
[(r/10,len([x for x in c if x>r/10])) for r in range(10)]
```

Comment: It isn't explicit whether the OP is on Python 3, where `r/10` will return a float. Also, why recalculate `r/10`. `10 * len(c)` times where you could generate the actual thresholds from the get-go with `np.arange()`?

Comment: yes, right. but will be clear in the tuple what threshold was used. `np.linspace` is perhaps a better choice but didn't want to impose numpy.

Comment: Both are straightforward to generate the thresholds for this example, though which is more direct is up to opinions. The user is explicitly using numpy, so there is no point not to utilise it But at the end of the day, it was all just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the sizes of your arrays, but your current solution has `O(m*n)` complexity, `m` being the number of values to test and `n` the size of your array.  You may be better off with `O((m+n)*log(n))` by first sorting your array in `O(n*log(n))` and then using binary search to find the `m` values in `O(m*log(n))`.  Using numpy and your sample `c` list, this would be something like:

```
>>> c
[0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1]
>>> thresholds = np.linspace(0, 1, 10, endpoint=False)
>>> thresholds
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])

>>> len(c) - np.sort(c).searchsorted(thresholds, side='right')
array([12, 10,  8,  5,  5,  3,  2,  1,  1,  0])
```